# Poker bankroll management in cash game

Tags: poker-strategy

A player has a bankroll of Rs. 200 k and has 4 different ids on 4 different websites .
He has to play only cash games and no MTT’s on all 4 ids every day . 
Playing cash games is his only profession and no other work so he can play full time .
So what will be his Modus operandi to get the maximum returns in 6 months and what will be his bankroll after 6 months according to the playing strategy provided by you?
Withdrawal limit every day for each Id is 9999/- only and daily withdrawal is also necessary which will not exceed 39996/-.
State your proper strategy which includes a logical figure of daily withdrawal and daily deposits taking into account the swings and the variances , the blinds you play and the stack with which you start the table on the first day till your last 180th day. No MTT only cash game .

Comment: R's are rupees?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is moot.
Since you can only withdraw 9999 per site per day and can only withdraw 24 days in a month (rest are banking holidays) the maximum you can withdraw is 24*6*39996 = 5759424.
Now again since you can only withdraw 9999 per site per day it means you need to win an average of 9999 per day with sunday being a buffer day.

Realistically if you want smooth sailing you need to follow the following strategy.

1.Play only 2 25/50 tables per site at a time and only 2 sites at a time.. sit with the with not more that 50 BB.. since you only need to win 200BB on each site. You should change tables often very often .. hit and run so to speak.

2.Play to a target and a stop loss.. initially while you are trying to stabilize you BR you need to play longer sessions and more carefully.. meaning you need to target winning 15k a day so you can withdraw 5k and and a 7k a day stop loss..

3. Make notes and target specific players.. I identify which players are volatile and play them . Do not play regs or sharks as they are on a similar strategy as you.
4. Deposit 25k on each site initially and grind for 2 weeks -3 weeks and increase you BR to alteals 100k each.. then play to maintain this level and withdraw 9999. Per site per day after this. Keep the rest of the money as a reserve and deposit if you  go bust on some site.
5. Realistically if you play an absolute perfect game then you will only manage a withdrawal for 100 out of the 144 days you can so the max return you can target is 4000k in 6 months.. but realistically even the top earners will earn at most 2500k in 6 months.. give. The above strategy
6. You are planning to play in India where Omaha is the preferred game.. given the volatility of the Indian Omaha scene you should expect much higher variances you may want to revise to daily target after your BR reaches 100k each to 20k up an 12k stoploss

Answer (score 0):

A lot of what you are asking depends on the player with this bankroll.

I will **assume** that the player you are referring to in your question has the following characteristics:

- plays perfect balance of GTO and exploitative play
- Has many monitors and is capable of playing a large number of tables at one time
- Plays a large amount of hours over the course of the 180 days

To get the maximum out of this bank roll, this player should withdraw the maximum from each ID every day. They should split the money into as many tables as possible and buy in for the maximum at each table. so around 9999 will be in play at once, a little bit could be saved for rebuys if needed. This perfect player should have tables open from all 4 sites at once and have as many open as possible (20-30 is the most i have seen anyone able to play).

Estimating the daily bankroll changes (and therefore the final estimated bankroll) of a player like this is nearly impossible because of the following unknown information:

- hands per hour
- playstyle
- opponents playstyle
- difficulty of each table (skill of all other players combined)
- average pot size
- % of pots won

If you or someone else was planning on starting to play professionally with a bankroll, I would suggest starting small and gathering data on yourself to see if you are a winning or losing player. Applications like PokerTracker 4 give very good statistics on all of the unknown things above that I just mentioned. Try to play as many hands as possible and gather a lot of data, this will make an extrapolation to a 180 day run much more accurate.

Most likely, the player you are referring to is not a perfect player, therefore taking some cautious steps like playing smaller games and not using all of each days allowed withdrawls would reduce risk.